# From which Gayatri Mantra is this part taken?

Tags: identification-request, gayatri-mantra

[image]

The emblem of the Ramakrishna Math and Mission bears a part of some Gayatri Mantra that reads : TAN NO HAMSAH PRACHODAYAT

From which Gayatri is this part taken? Please cite proper **scriptural** source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I received the original mantra and source from a friend of mine who is a monk of the Ramakrishna order.

The Gayatri Mantra is a part of the **Medha-Suktam** (Taittiriya Aranyakam-4,prapatak-10,Anubak 41-44).

The Gayatri Mantra reads as

> ॐ हंस हंसाय विद्महे परमहंसाय धीमहि तन्नो हंसः प्रचोदयात्

Here **Hamsa is the Paramatma in the form of Surya.Because just the previous line reads 'Mayi Suryo bhrajo dadhatu**.

Hamsa is a name of Surya as per the sanskrit dictionary also.

There is no name mentioned like 'हंस-गायत्री' by the way.

Comment: Good answer. One can read complete medha suktam from http://www.vignanam.org/veda/medha-suktam-english.html

Answer (score 3):

It can be one of the following three mantras:

> Om hamsa hamsaya vidmahe param hamsaya dhimhai tanno hamsah
>   prachodayat |
>
> Om hamsaya vidmahe param hamsaya dhimahi tanno hamsah prachodayat |
>
> Om param hamsaya vidmahe param tattvaya dhimahi tanno hamsah
>   prachodayat |

All these three mantras are listed under Parabrahma Gayatris in the PDF [Gayatri Worship](https://ambaa.org/pdf/gAyatrI_Worship.pdf) (p 112)

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Whats the original scripture?

Comment: That I don't know, I think u asked which Gayatri is that portion part of? @Partha

Comment: must be from some scripture as Swamiji quoted.

Comment: so sorry these lines are containing many mistakes:(Does not seem from reliable source.Kindly check

Comment: I don't know the scriptural source so I m deleting the answer

Comment: I don't know the scriptural sources of any of the 3 mantras .. but the 4th mantra in the screenshot is from Mahanirvana Tantram @Partha

Comment: with a visarga after brahma?