Need origin and more information about this mantra
I came across this mantra -
Om Paramahansaya Vidmahe
Mahatattvaya dhi mahi
Tannoh Hamsah Prachodayat
Please note it is different to all 3 mantras below -
Om hamsa hamsaya vidmahe param hamsaya dhimhai tanno hamsah prachodayat |
Om hamsaya vidmahe param hamsaya dhimahi tanno hamsah prachodayat |
Om param hamsaya vidmahe param tattvaya dhimahi tanno hamsah prachodayat |
Can anyone help with its origin, and any info on this mantra? While I read in one place it is a Hamsa Gayatri mantra, there is another Hamsa Gayatri mantra that is found everywhere and the Internet seems to have almost nothing on this particular mantra. Thanks in advance 

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33767/from-which-gayatri-mantra-is-this-part-taken/33768#33768

This question is similar to: From which Gayatri Mantra is this part taken?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
